# How to enable or disable a ClusteredScheduledTask in Powershell 4.0

Tags: scheduled-task, task-scheduler, powershell-v4.0

Reference to this page: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj649815.aspx

I'm finding ClusteredScheduledTasks a bit daunting to handle without a GUI interface.

For example, they have a Disable-ScheduledTask cmdlet.  Could I run that against a ClusteredScheduleTask?  If not, what would be the procedure to enable or disable a clustered schedule task?

Are many people actually using the Windows feature of ScheduledClusteredTasks, or do they get some third party utility?

Answer (score 1):

The proper procedure is to use `Unregister-ClusteredScheduledTask`cmdlet.

The Unregister-ClusteredScheduledTask cmdlet removes a clustered scheduled task from all nodes of a failover cluster

Comment: I don't want to remove it, just disable it for maybe an hour, then re-enable it.  Is that not possible?

Comment: You can try piping it to disable-scheduledtask `get-ClusteredScheduledTask | disable-scheduledtask`.